# Multivariable Calculus: How to show a limit does not exist, not using the two path method

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

My professor in multivariable calc challenged us to prove a limit of a function does not exist, without using a two path method. The particular equation we have to show it for it $$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2ye^y}{x^4+4y^2}.$$ I dont even have an idea of where to start, I was thinking of using the squeeze theorem but its used to show a limit does exist, and I have no idea how to use it to show it does not exist. Any ideas?

Comment: limiting point is the origin?

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot to put that in

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n = 1/(n\pi),$ and consider $f$ evaluated along the sequence of points $(x_n,(-1)^nx_n^2),n=1,2,\dots $